# Firefox (via jQuery) reports wrong height for image without src attribute

Tags: jquery, html, image, height, src

http://jsfiddle.net/2N854/

html:

```
<img alt="test" width="100" height="100">
```

javascript:

```
alert($('img').height());
```

On most browsers (chrome), the alert displays "100" as one would expect.  On firefox, it does not.  It "helpfully" converts the img into something that looks like:

```
<div>test</div>
```

.. and reports the height of that - "19" in my case.  I can work around the problem by assigning a placeholder src right before I check the height, and that works ok.

I didn't really forget the src attribute, rather I am in the process of computing it client-side.

I guess my question is - is there some way to disable this firefox "helpfulness"?

Comment: If you assign a `src` to the img tag, it'll work as expected.  The `src` tag is required, so what a browser does when it's missing isn't defined by any standard.

Comment: Even with an (admittedly 404) src attribute firefox reports the wrong height: http://jsfiddle.net/2N854/3/

Comment: Have you tried it with an actual image?  Are you really concerned about the behavior when the image link is broken?

Comment: Yes, @SamDufel, that was the point of the question.  As I say in the Q: "I can work around the problem by assigning a placeholder src right before I check the height, and that works ok."  Consider it a theoretical problem.  Workarounds abound.  I'm trying to find the cleanest solution - and I really like Zoltan's.  I just did one other test showing that FF will report the correct computed size if it hasn't had a chance to load the image.  It's only after it has noticed that the image is a 404 that it starts being "helpful."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can assign `display: inline-block` to your image - http://jsfiddle.net/2N854/1/ and FF will behave :)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but couldn't you just use `$('img').attr('height')` instead?

Comment: That won't work, because I sometimes use css to override the height attribute and I want the computed height.